# Is reselling online currency of a Website illegale?

Tags: website, currency

On the Website "abcdef.com" You can get credits by doing actions like watching something or buying them for real money. With the credits you can let other people do actions for you.
I found a way to make thousands of actions a second.
On the page there is a special premium member function to transfer credits to other users. I have so many credits I want to sell my credits to others. I have a website where I sell my credits via PayPal, is this legal because the page gives me the function to send credits or is it illegal because only the original page is allowed to sell credits for real money ?

Comment: Have you tried reading the terms and conditions for the website? I'd be surprised if there was no mention of this there...

Comment: I have read the Terms, they are pretty short, the site is not really big or anything. 
No information about selling Credits or anything.

Comment: What jurisdiction is this in? What country, and if the US or another federal country, what state or province?

Comment: There is no real information on the page itself, so I looked the domain up. The Registration information: 

Registrant City: Denver 
Registrant State/Province: CO

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [this question](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/9674/10).  Might also be informed by [this one](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/38879/10).